# Displacement map creates gaps on the corners of a wall

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, uv, displacement, bump

I'm able to create this bump effect using a brick texture on a plane with a displacement map, but when I tried to apply it on my current model it creates gaps or "holes" on the corner.

[image]

What I want is that on the corner the texture connect like it should be in real life, if that makes sense.

I already tried to add bevel on the corner but it didn't solve the problem, there's still a hole in it.

Here is screenshot for the node and uv unwrapping.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I believe this is not possible using node based displacement. You may have to use the displacement modifier instead.

Comment: enabling auto smooth solve this problem apparently, thanks for your comment

Comment: @Hilmy if auto smooth fixed it please add an answer (perfectly fine to answer your own questions) and show how.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that enabling "Auto-Smooth" fixes it.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]